# Expand a jquery collapse from an external link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to expand a jquery collapse by clicking on an external link?  For example: on the home page we have a link to another page and when the user clicks on the link from the home page, we want it to go the internal page and expand the collapsed jquery section that it corresponds to.

Comment: you can send a param via url to expand the section , post your code so others can help you

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible directly, however you can pass the required information via the URL hash and put the expand code in the target page:

**Home page:**

```
<a href="internal.html#section1">Go to section 1</a>
```

**Internal page:**

```
$(function() {
  var elem = $('#' + location.hash);
  // expand elem here
});
```

Comment: Perfect! My code looks like the following: 
**Internal Page
$(function() {
  var elem = $('#expand-4' + location.hash); 
 $('#expand-4-text').slideToggle('fast', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
$('#expand-4').toggleClass('expand-4-expanded');
});